# Inject html to new invoice e-mail

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, sales-order

I'm observing email_invoice_set_template_vars_before event.

And i want to alter event data. I'm doing it like this:

```
$transport = $observer->getData('transport');

doMagic($transport);

$observer->setData('transport', $transport);
```

But, it won't alter the data. Outside of my observer.

---

I'm using very similar approach with email_order_set_template_vars_before event. Just with difference, that transport is object with setter and getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exact answer, but i solved it by creating plugin for

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template
```

and creating

```
public function aroundSetTemplateVars(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template\Interceptor $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    array $vars
)
```

That way i can alter e-mail variables.